# Push notification "Don't allow" button action is not behaving as expected in my application

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I implemented a iOS application. I found a strange behavior for push notification in my application.

When I launch the application first time Push notification alert will come with two options.
one is "Don't allow" and another one is "Ok".

If I tap on "Don't allow" button , the Badge, Alert and Sound button state should be OFF in settings->Notification center->myApp.

But this in not happening in my application.

Once user tap on "Don't allow" button in the push notifications in my application ,  the Badge, Alert and Sound button state is showing as ON in settings->Notification center->myApp.

Why my app is behaving like this ? Can any one help me on this please.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

if you'll be able to have the action event on button then you can put this code in Don't allow action event

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 1];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

i hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Notification center for an allows us to customize how the notifications can be present for an app. ie like an alert view or notifications at the top like in Android. It has nothing to with the push notification enabled or not.

Comment: First of all Thanks for your quick reply.

I verified so many push notification related applications in AppStore. In all applications if user tap on "Don't allow" button in push notification alert , by default sound, badge and alert state is becoming OFF in device settings.

Do we neet to write any specific code for that ?

Comment: In my application I used the following code snippet to initialize the push notification.

(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

}

Please tell me this is correct approach or not ?

Comment: Still I am facing this issue , Any help please

Comment: @user1249854 It is the correct approach for registering push notification. If you want to reset the push notification permissions you have to uninstall the app atleast  for one day according to the link https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4721090

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing correct steps but If you want to reset notification permissions you can follow these steps: Settings >> General >> Reset >> Erase All Content and Settings. Or uninstall app wait for 24hours and then install again.